# C# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I have scaffolded Identity and it worked, but then I wanted to add `IdentityRole`, I get an error.

In `program.cs` I have this code:

```
builder.Services
           .AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

When I change it to

```
builder.Services
           .AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
```

It stops and throws error at:

```
app.MapRazorPages();
```

Error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddRazorPages' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.'

How do I fix it?

Comment: Well, did you try doing as the error suggests? `builder.Services.AddRazorPages()`

Comment: Thank you it works, for me wasn't clear what IServiceColletion is